# Calculating number of adjacent odd numbers

Tags: python, count

I am trying to write a code in Python where the user is asked to enter the number of numbers in a sequence, then the numbers themselves. And finally, the program outputs the number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers. Here's a sample output:

**Enter the length of the sequence: 6
 
Enter number 1: 3
 
Enter number 2: 4
 
Enter number 3: 7
 
Enter number 4: 9
 
Enter number 5: 3
 
Enter number 6: 5
 
The number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers is 3**

I have come up with the following code:

```
length = eval(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))

for i in range(1,length+1):
    ask = eval(input("Enter number: "+str(i)+ ": "))
    for m in range(0,length+1,2):
        ask2 = ask

h = ask%2
f = ask2%2

if h>0 and f>0:
    k = (len(str(ask) + str(ask2)))
    print(k)

else:
    pass
```

Although the output for the prompts are correct, I am unable to count the number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers. Please help me correct my code or build on it; this will be highly appreciated. As you must have noticed, I have been using basic if statements, loops and strings to write the code. It would be great if you could stick to this for my better understanding.

Sorry for the long post.

Thank you so much

Comment: don't use eval. cast to int.

Comment: Tried doing that, still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem.

First take the input given by the user into the list called numList. Keep a count variable to count the number of adjacent odd numbers. Loop through the numList one by one and identify the odd numbers by checking the remainder when divided by 2. (it is checked by the if condition given) Then you can simply print the number of adjacent odd numbers in the list.

```
length=int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))
numList=[]
count=0
for i in range(length):
    num=int(input("Enter number "+str(i+1)+ ": "))
    numList.append(num)

for x in range(len(numList)-1):
    num1=numList[x]
    num2=numList[x+1]
    if((num1%2==1) and (num2%2==1)):
        count=count+1
    else:
        continue

print("The number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers is "+str(count))
```

This is the answer if you want to solve this without the use of lists.
You should process the inputs as and when they are taken in.

```
length=int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))
count=0
num1=int(input("Enter number "+str(1)+ ": "))
for i in range(length-1):
    num2=int(input("Enter number "+str(i+2)+ ": "))
    if((num1%2==1) and (num2%2==1)):
        count=count+1
    num1=num2


print("The number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers is "+str(count))
```

Comment: Since I haven't yet covered lists in my programming class, I am not supposed to use that. Is there any way you can do it without the help lists?

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. But I don't understand one part of the code. Would you mind explaining it to me? According to what I know, the range function in a for loop works as follows:\br
**for i in range(a)** \br
the loop will execute up to (a-1) \br
In your part of the code: **for i in range(length-1):**, the loop should execute until (a-2), right? But it doesn't! I would be grateful if you could explain that to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jspake  As you can see,before the for loop, I have put a line for taking num1 in first. So that means, already 1 number from the total count of the numbers that you are going to input to the program is taken in before entering the for loop. So the for loop should iterate only 1 less than the length. So in Your case the loop will iterate 5 times. (from 0 to 4)

Comment: @TharikaMadurapperuma: Nice work. I'd probably do the range starting from 2: it makes it a little more obvious that it's iterating from the 2nd number onward, and it makes the addition (`str(i+2)`) in the loop unnecessary.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, that is true. I agree. :)

Answer (score 1):

check if the current element and the next are both odd and sum:

```
length = int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))

nums = [int(input("Enter number: {}: ".format(i))) for i in range(1, length + 1)]


print(sum(ele % 2 and nums[i] % 2 for i,ele in enumerate(nums, 1)))
```

`enumerate(nums, 1)` starts the index at `1` so `ele % 2 and nums[i] % 2` checks the current element as we iterate over nums with the next adjacent number.

Use `int(input..` when you want to cast to an int, using eval is never a good idea. You should also  probably use a `while` loop and verify the user input with a `try/except`.

Without using lists:

```
length = int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))
total = 0
# get a starting number
ask = int(input("Enter number: {}".format(1)))
# will keep track of previous number after first iteration
prev = ask
for i in range(2, length + 1):
    ask = int(input("Enter number: {}".format(i)))
    # if current and previous are both odd increase count
    if ask % 2 and prev % 2:
        total += 1
    # update prev 
    prev = ask

print(total)
```

Comment: Have you used lists to solve this problem? If yes, I am not supposed to use lists because we haven't yet covered this in my programming class. Is there any way you can solve it without the help of lists?

Comment: @Jspake, yep definitely use lists.  What can you use?

Comment: @Padriac I have been instructed not to use lists for coding. I'm pretty sure there is a way to solve it without the use of lists

Comment: @Jspake,  added how to do it using loops only

Comment: @Padriac Thanks for the effort. I tried running the code, it doesn't give the correct output.

Comment: @Jspake, it works fine for me and on the input you provided, can you provide an example of how it does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with simple `for` loops. Like's Padraic's solution it uses a list to accumulate the inputs, as it's simpler than trying to test the pairs as you're reading them in. As Padraic mentions, you really should check that the inputs are correct.

```
length = int(input("Enter the length of the sequence: "))

seq = []
for i in range(1, length + 1):
    ask = int(input("Enter number " + str(i) + ": "))
    seq.append(ask)

count = 0
for i in range(length - 1):
    if seq[i] % 2 == 1 and seq[i+1] % 2 == 1:
        count += 1

print("The number of pairs of adjacent odd numbers is", count)
```

Comment: Since I haven't yet covered lists in my programming class, I am not supposed to use that. Is there any way you can do it without the help lists?

Comment: @Jspake: I won't bother doing a list-less version, as I see the others have already done so. But IMHO Python without lists is like skiing with one arm tied behind your back - possible, but awkward. :)